# Retrieving "views" in Access 2010

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010, erd

My SQL Code:

```
    SELECT EmpLastName +', '+ EmpFirstName AS ProgramSupervisorName, TeamNo
    FROM Employee, Salary, ProgramSupervisor
    WHERE Employee.EmpNo = Salary.EmpNo
    AND Salary.EmpNo = ProgramSupervisor.EmpNo
    ORDER BY TeamNo
```

I realize that Access doesn't support creating views. The problem I'm running into is that I'm looking to group employees by ProgramSupervisor name but program supervisors and employees are both part of the employee table. The different types of employees are differentiated by their PosNo and employees belong to ProgramSupervisors through a series of tables (Hourly --> ISL <--- ProgramSupervisor). That being said, I can't reference ProgramSupervisorName and EmpName AS a renamed field in just one SELECT Statement because they are from the same table, differentiated by their positionNo. I was hoping I could create a query or "view", like the code above, that takes care of pulling the ProgramSupervisor name from the employee table then using that view in another query. In the other query I could then use the code : "EmpLastName +', '+ EmpFirstName AS EmpName."  The pages I've searched online are too vague for my limited understanding so please explain to me simply. I'll try to clarify any confusion also. I'll include my ERD so you can see where I'm coming from:

[image]

EDIT: query so far

```
   SELECT EmpLastName +', '+ EmpFirstName AS EmpName, ProgramSupervisorName, 
   ProgSupName.TeamNo          
   FROM Employee, ISL, Hourly, Salary, ProgramSupervisor, ProgSupName
   WHERE Employee.EmpNo = Hourly.EmpNo
   AND Hourly.ISLNo = ISL.ISLNo
   AND Employee.EmpNo = Salary.EmpNo
   AND Salary.EmpNo = ProgramSupervisor.EmpNo
   AND ProgramSupervisor.EmpNo = ISL.ProgramSupervisor_EmpNo
   ORDER BY ProgSupName.TeamNo
```

Do I need to relate all of these tables if I've done them already in the ProgSupName query?

Comment: Access does have views, it calls them queries

Comment: Right, but how can you retrieve a query in another query?

Comment: just use the query name like you would a table. Exactly the same way views work.

Comment: Great. Could you provide an example just so I don't mess up the syntax?

Comment: Is that ERD enough? The only tables I'd be using for such a query would be Employee, Salary, ProgramSupervisor, ISL, and Hourly. They are all related to eachother in the database the exact way and have the same exact field names.

Comment: @BenignBaboon. I read your question a couple of times and couldn't understand what you want from this table. can you be a little more clear on that? You just want to know how to use a subquery as a view?

Comment: How about you try and use the feature first and ask further questions if you find problems?

Comment: I apologize. Basically, I want to use a query inside another query but I'm unsure how to go about it. The query I have at the top part of my post is called 'Program Supervisor Name.' I want to use the field "ProgramSupervisorName" from the 'Program Supervisor Name' query (I know, no the best naming) in another query. Help a little?

Comment: @Laurence I'm trying that right now. Still trying to figure out some how to reference some of the tables. Will let you know, thanks.

Comment: I just tried referencing the query inside another and it worked! The only problem is that no results showed up because my logic is not right. I'll post what I have so far of the query. The Hourly employees belong to an ISL and the ISL's are headed by a ProgramSupervisor (ProgramSupervisor_EmpNo). I want to list all of the Hourly employee's according the ProgramSupervisor that is the head of the ISL they belong to....and only display the the Hourly employee name, Program Supervisor name, and team no(teamNo is not important).

Answer (score 1):

> I realize that Access doesn't support creating views.

For the record, Access does support the creation of saved Queries, which are just "Views" by another name. (In fact, the OLEDB variant of Access SQL DDL does support `CREATE VIEW` as a way of creating a saved Query.)

Answer (score 0):

The key to answering this question lies in two parts:

The first is using an Access stored query like a view.  That has been answered here.

The second is referencing the same table twice in a query using different column or table aliases.  That has been asnwered in the correct answer you got to your other question, asked here:
[Displaying the same fields AS different names from the same table -Access 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035417/displaying-the-same-fields-as-different-names-from-the-same-table-access-2010)

Combine those two answers, and you have the solution.